# How to resolve scrollToRowAtIndexPath not working when view disappear?

Tags: ios, uitableview

A main view controller has a table view and here is the process to see the problem:

1. Main view controller is presented and the table view is on the screen
2. A Safari View Controller is presented
3. Rotate the device.
4. The app calls `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` on the table view (cells have different heights for portrait/landscape mode, need to call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` to the first cell before rotation so that the user can see the same cells after rotation)
5. Close Safari View Controller
6. `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` had no effect on the table view.

If step 2 is ignored, `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` works.

I am planning to solve the problem by calling `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` in `viewDidAppear` in the main view controller. However, is there a better way or maybe I have missed something?

Comment: Where do you call "scrollToRowAtIndexPath"?

Comment: @almas in `viewWillTransitionToSize`

Comment: Can you try "viewWillAppear"?

Comment: @almas well, I will try both `viewDidAppear` & `viewWillAppear`, but I am looking for some other directions & suggestion, or it's just the same as my current plan. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I don't think calling it in "viewWillTransitionToSize" is a good idea, because your table view didn't resize yet at that moment. "viewDidAppear" is too late to call it - it will work, but user will see it, and it won't be nice. So "viewWillAppear" should be the best for it.

Comment: I checked again, I actually call it in a completion handler `coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition` in `viewWillTransitionToSize`... not before the table view resizes.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, to call it in `viewWillAppear`, it does not work. My question is towards the case when switching to the other view controller, how to adjustment the row position before switching back.  Please consider the exact situation I am having the issue .

Comment: It works just fine in my project, I'll create a github repo for you in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Use "viewWillAppear". I created a sample project for you: https://github.com/almas73/ScrollToRow

Comment: Sorry, I really don't think you understand my question.

Comment: Have you looked at the project? It does exactly what you described. If not, then you should explain better what you are trying to achieve.